# SOAP API: SiteTraversal WSDL return 404

Tags: yodlee

I'm trying to retrieve all the available sites from the Yodlee API.
As I did for User Registration or Cobrand Login, I tried to obtain the list of available method on the WSDL endPoint.
Basically, I pass this to my yodlee url + / services url :
SiteTraversalService?wsdl

But all I receive is a 404.

```
Wasabi::Resolver::HTTPError: Error: 404
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee Service URL 404s generally happen because the the URL in fact is incorrect.

This can happen because of several reasons.

1. Either the URL is invalid
2. The Version was not specified in the Service Url (and the functionality you requested is not available in the fail-over API version).

**To check if your URL is valid/invalid you need to enable tracing so you can see the exact request url that went out.**

If you're on Windows you may find [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com) to be very useful for this. (You will need to enable the requirements for [sniffing/decrypting](http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS) SSL Traffic). For other platforms the SDK Guide has some other alternatives.

Once you've ensured that the URL is valid the next step is making sure you're specifying the version.

**Newer API functionality is not available in older API Versions.** You specify the Version in your Service Url URL which determines the functionality that is available to you. Yodlee versions are appended to the Service Page Url in the form of _Major_Minor (12.0 and 11.1) would be _12_0 or _11_1

**Example:**

```
new EndpointAddress(BaseServiceUrl + Name_TransactionDataService + ServiceVersionPrefix)
```

where

- BaseServiceUrl is your base Yodlee url (provided by your rep or Yodlee Dev Center)
- Name_TransactionDataServices is say "TransactionDataService"
- and VersionPrefix would be your version/sub version in the format of "_12_0" or "_11_1" (12.0 or 11.1).

So your url should look/resemble the following:

```
https://yodleedomain/yodsoap/services/TransactionDataServices_12_0
```

(I do not append the ?WSDL to the url).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, even if enter `https://yodleedomain/yodsoap/SiteTraversalService_12_0?wsdl`, I obtain a 404.

Comment: oups, I meant `https://yodleedomain/yodsoap/services/SiteTraversalService_12_0?wsdl`

Comment: Make sure you replace (https://yodleedomain/yodsoap/services) with the proper API url (this is given by either the Yodlee Dev Site) or your (Representative if you've signed up).

Comment: I'm in Private Zone for Implementation & Testing, do you think it can have any impact?

Comment: That's where I Tested it. I believe you need to do what I originally suggested and enable tracing. If you're on Windows you can use Fiddler.  You need to see and provide the specific details for the request that you are sending out.

Comment: The 404 can also be from a result of making a GET request when you should be POSTing and/or may also be the behavior if you've not passed a proper cobrand context. The Trace should be able to show this.

Comment: got it! Actually the URL is OK with _12_0 but no WSDL file anyway. When I try to getAllSites, no way, I obtain `Unable to find SOAP operation: :getAllSites`

Comment: Your SDK has a wsdl folder which has all of the WSDL. I do not know if you are able to get the WSDL from the service or not.

Comment: Regarding the unable to find SOAP operation. I would hazard a guess you're not logged in. However, I am merely guessing. **You need to provide a trace of what was submitted.**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the connectivity to the Yodlee service, do the following --

Invoke -- `https://yodleedomain:port/yodsoap/services/listservices`